# Flexbox 3 column to 2 column (2 sidebars to a single sidebar)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a flexbox solution 3 columns on a large screen...

```
+-----+ +----------+ +-----+
|     | |          | |     |
|  A  | |    B     | |  C  |
|     | |          | |     |
|     | |          | +-----+
+-----+ |          | 
        +----------+
```

that would change to ...

```
+-----+ +----------+ 
|     | |          | 
|  A  | |    B     | 
|     | |          | 
|     | |          | 
+-----+ |          | 
+-----+ |          |
|     | +----------+
|  C  |
|     |
+-----+
```

on smaller screens, where A, B and C can have variable height.  Basically B would be the main content and A and C would be the sidebars.

Comment: Have you tried anything? We help you fix your code, not write it for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<body class="HolyGrail">
  <header>…</header>
  <div class="HolyGrail-body">
    <main class="HolyGrail-content">…</main>
    <nav class="HolyGrail-nav">…</nav>
    <aside class="HolyGrail-ads">…</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```